Retrieving all holders of a given token
How do I retrieve all accounts holding a given token (e.g., Bonk) and their balances via APIs?

You can use getProgramAccounts for this. You'd need to filter by:
a) Token account
b) Token mint
Example:
curl http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 10,
    "method": "getProgramAccounts",
    "params": [
      "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed",
        "filters": [
          {
            "dataSize": 165
          },
          {
            "memcmp": {
              "offset": 0,
              "bytes": "Token mint"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }'

Here, 165 is the length of a Solana token account. This method would return all "token accounts", not the actual holder wallets though.
If you want a quicker, faster and easier solution, you can use Helius' getTokenAccounts method, more about it: https://www.helius.dev/blog/how-to-get-token-holders-on-solana

You can use Bitquery Solana APIs for this.
Bitquery Solana API full docs- https://docs.bitquery.io/docs/category/solana/
Check example below to get top 100 token holders of a particular token, try the API directly on ide.bitquery.io:
query MyQuery {
  Solana(dataset: realtime) {
    BalanceUpdates(
      limit: { count: 100 }
      orderBy: { descendingByField: "BalanceUpdate_Holding_maximum" }
      where: {
        BalanceUpdate: {
          Currency: {
            MintAddress: { is: "2GxdEZQ5d9PsUqyGy43qv4fmNJWrnLp6qY4dTyNepump" }
          }
        }
        Transaction: { Result: { Success: true } }
      }
    ) {
      BalanceUpdate {
        Currency {
          Name
          MintAddress
          Symbol
        }
        Account {
          Address
        }
        Holding: PostBalance(maximum: Block_Slot)
      }
    }
  }
}

Full Disclosure: I work at Bitquery
